# Copiar imagenes del disco local a la carpeta resources JSF

Tags: imagen, jsf

Estoy usando un componente p:galleria, este componente funciona unicamente con las imágenes que se encuentran en la carpeta resources, esto es lo que estoy intentando pero no se copian los archivos y solo muestra cuadros en blanco.

```
<p:commandButton id="botonImg" value="Ver/Ocultar imagenes" update="galeria,growl" actionListener="#{bean.listarImagenes()}" />
<p:galleria id="galeria" value="#{bean.listaImagenes}" var="image" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true">
  <p:graphicImage name="images/#{image}" title=" " alt=" " style="width:100%" height="313" />
</p:galleria>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>rutaImagenesGaleria</param-name>
    <param-value>/resources/images/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**bean**

```
public void listarImagenes() throws Exception {
        List<String> listaRutas = new ArrayList<>();
        ImagenesFacade imagenesFacade = new ImagenesFacade(
                RUTA_PROPERTIES);

        List<Imagenes> listaImagenes = imagenesFacade
                .obtenerImagenesPorID(key);

        for (Imagenes imagen : listaImagenes) {
            String ruta = imagen.getRuta();
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(ruta);
            String arr[] = ruta.split("/");
            String nombreArchivo = arr[arr.length - 1];
            InputStream imagenContenido = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            String rutaImagenTemporal = getExternalContext().getInitParameter("rutaImagenesGaleria");
            file = new File(rutaImagenTemporal+nombreArchivo);
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(imagenContenido, file);
            file.createNewFile();
            listaRutas.add(nombreArchivo);
        }
        this.listaImagenes = listaRutas;

    }

}
```

Comment: Que error te muestra el log?

Comment: Ninguno al aplastar el botón, pero al haces clic en los cudritos en blanco del carrusel dice WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-9) JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, images/nombredelarchivo.png.

Comment: Pero las imagenes si se guardan?

Comment: No, no se guardan

Comment: una manera algo rebuscada en que lo he logrado ha sido poniendo en el bean
System.getProperty("jboss.server.temp.dir") que regresa algo asi como C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\tmp y haciendo replace("tmp","deployments/proyecto.war/resources/images/"+nombrearchivo), pero no se si tenga que ver con el SO pero al intentarlo en Linux no me funcionó, la carpeta deployments estaba vacía. Entonces lo que intente hacer fue agregar en el web.xml la ruta de resources pero no dio resultado ni en Windows